# Replacing newline character

Tags: linux, sed, newline

I have an XML file which has occasional lines that are split into 2: the first line ending with `&#13;`. I want to concatenate any such lines and remove the `&#13;`, perhaps replacing it with a space.

e.g.

```
<message>hi I am&#13;
here </message>
```

needs to become

```
<message>hi I am here </message>
```

I've tried:

```
sed -i 's/&#13;\/n/ /g' filename
```

with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: SO correctly suggests this as a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a GNU `sed` version:

```
sed ':a;$bc;N;ba;:c;s/&#13;\n/ /g' file
```

#### Explanation:

```
sed '
    :a              # Create a label a
    $bc             # If end of file then branch to label c
    N               # Append the next line to pattern space
    ba              # branch back to label a to repeat until end of file
    :c              # Another label c
    s/&#13;\n/ /g   # When end of file is reached perform this substitution
' file
```

Comment: This worked after I ran dos2unix on my file. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F"&#13;" '/&#13;$/ {a=$1; next} a{print a, $0; a=""; next} 1' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-F"&#13;"` set `&#13;` as delimiter, so that the first field will be always the desired part of the string.
- `/&#13;$/ {a=$1; next}` if the line ends with `&#13;`, store it in `a` and jump to the next line.
- `a{print a, $0; a=""; next}` if `a` is set, print it together with current line. Then unset `a` for future loops. Finally jump to next line.
- `1` as true, prints current line.

#### Sample

```
$ cat a
yeah
<message>hi I am&#13;
here </message>
hello
bye

$ awk -F"&#13;" '/&#13;$/ {a=$1; next} a{print a, $0; a=""; next} 1' a
yeah
<message>hi I am here </message>
hello
bye
```

Answer (score 2):

give this gawk one-liner a try:

```
awk -v RS="" 'gsub(/&#13;\n/," ")+7' file
```

tested here with your example:

```
kent$ echo "<message>hi I am&#13;
here </message>"|awk -v RS="" 'gsub(/&#13;\n/," ")+7'  
<message>hi I am here </message>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you:

```
sed -i '{:q;N;s/&.*\n/ /g;t q}' <filename>
```

However replacing newline with sed is always a bash(read bad) idea. Chances of making an error are high.

So another but **simpler** solution:

```
tr -s '\&\#13\;\n' ' ' < <filename>
```

tr is replacing all chracter in match with space, so without `-s` it would have printed

```
<message>hi I am      here </message>
```

`-s` from man page:

```
   -s, --squeeze-repeats
          replace  each  input  sequence of a repeated character that is listed in SET1 with a single occurrence of that character.
```